# Automatic scaling of textarea height

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to display a double column layout. In the left column there is a picture which can be displayed as 30% or the available width but no more than 300px. In the right column there is a description that spans the rest of the browser width.

I do not know *a priori* how long the description is and I want to limit the height of the description field so I am using `textarea` to enable scrolling if needed.

This is my current HTML code:

```
<div class="tile-panel">
    <div class="tile-preview-panel">
        <img class="tile-img" src="{{ thumbnail_url }}">
    </div>
    <div class="tile-desc-panel">
        <textarea readonly class="form-control tile-description"> {{ desc }} </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.tile-panel {
      width: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
}
.tile-preview-panel {
      width: 30%;
      float:left;
      max-width: 300px;
}
.tile-desc-panel {
      overflow: hidden;
}
.tile-img {
      width: 100%;
}
.tile-description {
      resize: none;
      background-color:inherit !important;
      width: 100%;
}
.tile-description[readonly] {
      cursor: default; !important;
}
```

The only remaining bit is the height of the `textarea`. I want it always to be the height of the tile-preview-panel, regardless of the width of the browser. Is this achievable with pure CSS?

Comment: Are you looking for same `height` for both columns?

Comment: Yes, height for the first column should depend on the height of the image, which in theory can be anything. This in turn should define the height of the second column and the textarea.

Comment: Do you want to stick with `div` or possible for you to use `table` instead?

Comment: I would prefer to use div, but if can not get it to work, I would use table rather than change the concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a start, this one using your existing textarea,

```css
.tile-panel {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.tile-preview-panel {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30%;
}
.tile-desc-panel {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
}
.tile-img {
  width: 100%;
}
.tile-description {
  resize: none;
  background-color:inherit !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  }
.tile-description[readonly] {
  cursor: default; !important;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px){
  .tile-preview-panel {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tile-panel">
    <div class="tile-preview-panel">
        <img class="tile-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/1/">
    </div>
    <div class="tile-desc-panel">
        <textarea readonly class="form-control tile-description"> {{ desc }} </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is a version using a `div` instead, so you can style the text more, use links etc.

```css
.tile-panel {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.tile-preview-panel {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30%;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.tile-desc-panel {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.tile-img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.tile-description {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .tile-preview-panel {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tile-panel">
  <div class="tile-preview-panel"><img class="tile-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/5/"></div>
  <div class="tile-desc-panel">
    <div class="tile-description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
      dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also `flex` can be used, though it has slightly less browser support.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.pic {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.text {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.pic img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.text div {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/1/">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="tile-description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
      dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @pegazik My mistake, fixed that, updated answer. It needs to be set on the image.

Comment: But now even though image stays at the requested maximum size, the parent div still scales which pushes the second column away.

Comment: @pegazik Updated my answer, will work now as you wanted. Was a little bit trickier than expected :)

Comment: Thank you for such a complete answer. All works as charm! In particular `flex` property seems to be the neatest solution.

Comment: Just to comment about the way you remove the white space below the image, isn't using display:block or set a vertical-align value other than the default baseline better?

Comment: @Pangloss Of course it is :). I just learned about the `vertical-align` trick a couple of days ago. Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

i would use javascript for this

put this in the head

```
<script>

function sameheight(){
var divHeight = document.getElementById('DIV ID YOU WANT TO GET HEIGHT OF').style.height;
document.getElementById('DIV ID YOU WANT THE SAME SIZE').style.height = divHeight;
}
</script>
```

And put on your body

```
<body onload="sameheight()">
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would prefer to use css for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```css
.tile-panel {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.tile-preview-panel {
    position: relative; 
    width: 74%;
}
.tile-desc-panel {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0; 
    margin-left: 1.5%; 
    width: 24.5%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background: #232323; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tile-img {
      width: 100%;
}
.tile-description {
      resize: none;
      background-color:inherit !important;
      width: 100%;
}
.tile-description[readonly] {
      cursor: default; !important;
}

textarea {
  border: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="tile-panel">
    <div class="tile-preview-panel">
        <img class="tile-img" src="http://placehold.it/640x260">
    </div>
    <div class="tile-desc-panel">
        <textarea readonly class="form-control tile-description"> {{ desc }} </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the solution. I only added `height: 100%; !important;` to `.tile-description[readonly]` and it works! Thank you!

Comment: Got excited too early, it seems that the width of the second column is now being broken when I add `max-width: 300px;` to `.tile-preview-panel` (as in the original question). All works well when the first column is below 300px, but when it goes above, the second column stops filling the remaining width of the page. :(

Comment: @pegazik I believe the `height` issue is solved. Do you want that second column moves and come close accordingly when the image width is less? Can you create fiddle with the problem?

Comment: Yes, exactly, two divs should fill the whole width of the page efficiently. Second column should be (70% * page_width) when (30% * page_width) < 300px, and (page_width - 300px) otherwise.

Comment: Here is the fiddle to play around: https://jsfiddle.net/eyjanuq0/1/ It is my original code, widths scale correctly, heights do not.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant of using javascript as @user1899614 suggested but with ES6 and getBoundingClientRect() method:

```
const makeDimensionsEqual = (someTextareaSelector, someParentElementSelector) => {

  document.querySelectorAll(someTextareaSelector)[0].style.height = 
    document.querySelectorAll(someParentElementSelector)[0]
    .getBoundingClientRect().height + "px"

}

const someTextareaSelector = '...' 
const someParentElementSelector = '...'
makeDimensionsEqual(someTextareaSelector, someParentElementSelector)
```